# Transaction Control over a Connection Pool

Tags: java, multithreading, transactions, connection-pooling

I have a multithreaded application wherein am parsing a file and inserting into database - I have a db connection pool for writing to the database - I need to add a transaction control over the parse/write entire operation i.e. in case of any error during the parse/db-insert operation, I want to rollback the entire operation wherein my partial db writes need to be rolled back- is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to take the connection out of the pool, start the database transaction on it, and keep it out of the pool for the duration of the transaction. You'll only return it back to the pool once you finish (commit or rollback) the transaction.

This obviously means that you cannot run more transactions in parallel than you have connections in your pool. If you cannot accept this limitation, you'll have to devise your own workaround that doesn't rely on database transactions (e.g. using a "stage" table that accepts data with some unique identifier, then moving it into the main storage at once, plus a task to delete stale data).

I recommend reading on [Spring's transaction manager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) for an inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly you have an application which split the file into several parts, each part is parsed by a different thread and each uses its own connection from the pool.

I think the transaction manager could help here if you are fine to use XA transactions. Each of the connection would form a separate transaction branch thus each of the thread would then work on a separate participant of the transaction. At the end, 2PC would ensure to get all committed or rolled-back.